# Can a company cancel employment 1 day before start day

Tags: hiring-process, employment-agreement

I went through a very long process of interviewing and finally "the client" accepted and gave me a job offer(as a W2-consultant status) that I accepted.

I (docusign) signed an employment agreement to start the work on 5/22/2018 and then suddenly they (the employment agency) call me today (5/21/2018) to cancel the job because they say the client-company is going under some reorganization.

Is that OK for them to do that really? They wasted almost 45 days of my time.
Also, I neglected many other interviews I could have gone to.

Is there anything I legally do against that?

Comment: Contact a lawyer.

Comment: @solarflare that sounds like legal advice to me, and i kinda doubt toy have any idea what the cost and benefits would be.

Comment: I deleted my "legal advice" of saying it probably would be a waste of time and money.  This is not legal advice.

Comment: Taking legal action will only make you waste more time I think. It's better for you if you invest your time in job-hunting instead, but to know if you can do anything legally speaking I feel you would be better asking a lawyer you trust or that specializes in these sort of things.

Comment: @MMEL What is your country? I would read over your employment contract. If you are an at-will employee, the company can terminate your job at any time, but I would speak to a lawyer about your rights. Note: I am not a lawyer and cannot provide legal advice.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies, this is a contract is in English and for a company in Los Angeles, California.
A lawyer sounds like a good idea but also an expensive one and I wanted to know if, although this is a contract (fire at will type) and not an FTE (Full Time Employment) type position, can they really let me go, without having had me started yet and also let me know the day right before the job start day. Certainly not "nice", but can they legally really do that?

Comment: What a terrible situation for you, you need legal advise which is off topic here.

Comment: You have copy of the contract, read what it says about termination or cancellation.

Answer (score 6):

You *have* to consult with a lawyer.  It will vary by jurisdiction, but in *some* cases this could be taken to court. Most US states are [at-will employment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At-will_employment).  This means you can quit at any time, as well as being let go at any time.  However, if you can prove that accepting this offer has cost you resources and other job prospects, you *may* be entitled to compensation based on the laws of your jurisdiction.

In my opinion, that would be hard to prove.  You stated you "neglected" to go on other interviews.  Had you gone on those interviews and received offer letters and turned them down for this job, and these jobs were no longer available, then you *might* have a leg to stand on.  However, you did not go to these interviews and therefore were not offered the positions.  You cant prove loss of wages, if there were no wages to be lost.  Unfortunately, I think that would stop any possibility of compensation.

Again, you need to consult with a lawyer in your jurisdiction.

Edit:  Gotta love the random downvotes.  However, I know this to be true, as my best friend went through a similar scenario.  However, he was working at the time.  He did have other job offers.  He left his job, turned down the other offers, and moved to a different state, only to have the job terminated before he started.  He took them to court and won.

Comment: Presumably the OP is employed by the agency here